# lapack - addressing for fully packed rectangular format

Tags: lapack

I would like to use the LAPACK routines for factorisation and inversion of matrices using the fully packed rectangular format, as this requires only n(n+1)/2 elements to be stored for a symmetric nxn matrix. So far, I am setting up the matrix in 'packed' format and transform it calling routine DTPTTF. However, this requires a second array. I would like to build my matrix **directly** in fully packed rectangular format (to save on space) - is there an 'addressing' function which will give me the position of the i,j-th element? or could somebody point me to the relevant formula?

Answer (score 0):

to partly answer my own question: inspecting the source code of DTPTTF and the example given therein, I've worked out the adress for one of the four possible constellations (the only one I need), namely uplo ='L' and trans ='N'. below is my fortran function:

```
! ====================================     ! returns address for RFP format
  integer function ijfprf( ii, jj, n )     ! for row jj and column ii
! ====================================     ! for UPLO = 'L' and TRANSR = 'N' only!

  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: ii, jj, n
  integer             :: i, j, k, n1, k1

  if( ii <= jj ) then
      i = ii; j = jj
  else
      i = jj; j = ii
  end if
  k = n/2
  if( mod(n,2) == 0 ) then                     ! n even
      n1 = n + 1
      if( i <= k ) then
          ijfprf = 1 + (i - 1) * n1 + j
      else
          ijfprf = ( j - k - 1 ) * n1 + i - k
      end if
  else                                         ! n odd
      k1 = k + 1
      if( i > k1 ) then
          ijfprf = ( j - k1 ) * n + i - k1
      else
          ijfprf = ( i - 1 ) * n + j
      end if
  end if

  return
  end function ijfprf
```